# Why ISO master (editor) does not read Windows images

Tags: windows-7, iso

I have the followjng problem with ISO master software: I try to edit WIndows 7 ISO image

```
$ isomaster windows7.iso
```

The file does open, unfortunately all I get is README with message:

> This disc contains a "UDF" file system and requires an operating
>   system that supports the ISO-13346 "UDF" file system specification.

isomaster comes form Ubuntu repository, I am using 12.04. The system has kernel support for UDF installed, I can mount above ISO (`mount -o loop`) and see its content read only. Any idea how to fix it? Using other than isomaster tool is also an option.
Regards, Jacek

Comment: Why was this flagged off topic? **Question is about using Ubuntu software from the repos**.

Comment: Apparently `isomaster` does not support UDF.

Comment: ISO master is positioned ISO editor of choice on this forum. Lack of UDF support and consequently lack of Windows image editing capability is a serious drawback and should be clearly stated so people don't waste time attempting to do not doable.

Comment: @Jacek Blocki, that is a good point.  You should open a bug against the isomaster package to update their document to clearly state this information.

Comment: After looking at this app, I currently another app k3b shown in the reviews of this app say that it will work better.

Comment: This problem was solved here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531012/how-to-modify-an-installation-iso-and-keep-it-bootable

Answer (score 0):

I used to use isomaster, but ran into this issue. Now I just add stuff to my iso's manually.

```
mkdir new_iso
mount -o loop iso_file.iso /mnt/
sudo cp -Rva /mnt/* new_iso
#Make your changes in the new_iso directory
sudo umount /mnt
cd new_iso
sudo mkisofs -D -r -V "ISO NAME" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /home/USER/new.iso new_iso/
```

Answer (score 0):

The UDF filesystem does not automatically mount properly in Ubuntu.  See the question [How to open UDF Volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359264/how-to-open-udf-volume) for more info.

Comment: Please include essential parts here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by essential parts.

Answer (score -3):

The contents the Windows 7 ISO image file in question is copyrighted material. If you use the `udfinfo` utility from the `udftools` package, you can verify that the UDF filesystem in the Windows 7/10 ISO image is **read-only** and thus not editable.

Comment: Perhaps you should've added something useful, then people wouldn't have been too offended by you wondering what the intent is, and by even suggesting it, implying that something fishy is going on.