# How to open UDF Volume

Tags: mount, dvd, udf

I have a DVD which I can open in Windows, but in my Ubuntu 12.04 installation I cannot any more. I receive this error:

```
Unable to mount UDF Volume

Error mounting: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

What should I do to open it? Do I need to install anything?

Comment: How do I actually write to the UDF disc?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the terminal and try mounting the DVD with:

```
sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

The argument following the -t is used to indicate the filesystem type, which in this case is udf. UDF or Universal Disk Format is an operating-system-independent file system commonly used on DVD and other digital media.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDF</sub>

Comment: The answer also works when instead of physical DVD you have a file on disk that's a DVD image (maybe downloaded from somewhere).  Then you just replace /dev/sr0 by the file's pathname.  That was my problem today and your answer solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Not all DVDs are really udf, if the `-t udf` doesn't work (wrong superblock) try:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

that is after `sudo mkdir /cdrom` so the `/cdrom` directory exists.

```
~$ sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog -
       try `dmesg | tail`  or so

~$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /cdrom
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
~$ ls /cdrom
autorun.inf  casper  EFI      isolinux    pics  preseed             ubuntu
boot         dists   install  md5sum.txt  pool  README.diskdefines  wubi.exe
```

*Yet it is a DVD+R

Answer (score 2):

In my case (same case, DVDs playing in windows but not on Linux) I resolved it installing **[libdvdcss](https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html)**.

```sh
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg  # libdvdcss in Archlinux
```

Besides *libdvdcss* I would check also that is installed *libdvdread* and *libdvdnav*.

These libraries seem to be needed to play encrypted DVDs (and I wasn't aware that the DVDs were encrypted, but they use [Content Scramble System (CSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System) keys that needed to be retrieved through the libdvdcss library).