# How to extract iso images to the hard disk?

Tags: iso

I have some ISO images and would like to extract them to a hard-disk. They are not OS images, I think they are music or audio books, I Don't know until they are extracted.
Thanks

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
7z x disk.iso
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70738/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-extract-an-iso

See also:

- create ISO: [How to create an ISO image from a ZIP file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136165/how-to-create-an-iso-image-from-a-zip-file) It seems 7z can only unpack but not create ISO files?
- edit ISO: [How to edit ISO Images (Including Bootable ISOs)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46646/how-to-edit-iso-images-including-bootable-isos)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 with the [Ubuntu 18.04  ISO itself: `ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/).

Comment: This is an actual answer. Others just tell to mount and then copy. I can even burn a CD , climb on eiffel  tower, wear a blindfold, and copy the contents, while standing on my head, but that's not the point. If there is such a simple command "7z x". Why bother with all that complication?

Comment: 7z doesn't preserve permissions when extracting an ISO

Comment: @mheyman thanks for the report. And mount does is that correct? If that is the case it would be good to have a link to a feature request in their tracker.

Comment: Mounting as a loopback always works assuming you have the proper permissions and file system. The only robust non-mounting way I've found is using https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/ (there are usually packages available). Just make sure to use the -file_name_limit 253 option when extracting. For some reason it defaults to 64 which isn't long enough for may ISOs. (I've also had problems with file name lengths using 7z).

Comment: Late to the party but the current version of 7z expects 'e' as a parameter for extracting the iso.

Comment: How can I use this to extract the image in a different directory?

Comment: @MehdiCharife doesht `7z x path/to/disk.iso` work?

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com  It should, but I'm thinking of extracting the image in a directory that is different from the one in which the `.iso` file resides.

Comment: @MehdiCharife OK. `man 7z` says there's an `-o` option "Set Output directory", untested.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com The command `7z x -o /media/mehdi/7A70-A177/ kubuntu-22.10-desktop-amd64.iso` gives the error **Command Line Error:
Too short switch:
-o**

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com Oddly (ot not), removing the space between `-o` and the path of the destination fix the issue: `7z x -o/media/mehdi/7A70-A177/ kubuntu-22.10-desktop-amd64.iso`.

Comment: @MehdiCharife ah, their CLI interface if a bit wonky it seems!

Answer (score 29):

If you are comfortable with the command line you can make use of the loop-back device.

All you'll need is an empty folder, so either use an existing one or create an new one:

```
mkdir test_folder
```

then run:

```
sudo mount -o loop,ro -t iso9660 filename.iso test_folder
```

If you are not sure about the filesystem type of the .iso, your system might be able to auto-detect it. This works on Ubuntu 18.04 with the Ubuntu installation ISOs for example:

```
sudo mount filename.iso test_folder
```

Now you can just `cd test_folder` or just `ls test_folder` to see the contents. No need to extract anything.

To "remove" the .iso, just type:

```
umount /path/to/test_folder
```

Comment: I like this answer - I don't have "copies" of the contents of the ISO floating around...

Comment: leaving `-t iso9660` worked for WIndows 10 iso.

Comment: I got this error: `mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only`.  Do you have any idea why I got this?

Comment: It's not an error. It's just informing you that the image ismounted read-only. If you ls the folder you'll see the contents of the image.

Comment: You need root privileges to use mount with `-o`, I also added the -`ro`option.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu, you can open them in Archive Manger:
[image] 
You can add files  `.iso`s, and extract them.

To open it, right-click on the file and select <kbd>Open With →</kbd>, and <kbd>Archive Manager</kbd>. If the option is available, you can also mount the `.iso` image as though it was a disc in the computer.

If it is not installed *(it should be, I think it is part of the desktop)*, use this:

```
sudo apt-get install file-roller
```

You may also get an option to right-click and <kbd>Extract Here</kbd> to extract the contents of the iso files, and other compressed files.

Comment: file-roller fails to extract files larger than 2GB (file-roller uses isoinfo/isoread code and that code has a signed 32-bit integer used for the size of the file in bytes that overflows at 2GB)

Answer (score 1):

7z has a [bug that truncates file names longer than 64 characters](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/1055/) so I used CMake instead:

```sh
cmake -E tar xf filename.iso
```

(but any other [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/)-based tool should work, including [bsdtar](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/ManPageBsdtar1))

Answer (score 0):

Easyest way to extract iso file in linux is

Open terminal and type

`sudo su root`

enter your password then type

`mount -t auto -o loop "Path/location to iso" /where u want to mount`

Answer (score 0):

There is no official application to handle ISO-files on a Ubuntu plasma desktop environment, like Ubuntu Studio.

You can install Double Commander and extract an ISO directly using  your mouse with right click: extract here.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AcetoneISO

> **AcetoneISO** is often referred to as the Daemon Tools equivalent for GNU/Linux.
>   This mighty software can mount **ISO, MDF, BIN and NRG** files and burn
>   ISO images to optical discs. It supports file conversion from **BIN,
>   MDF, NRG, DAA, IMG, DMG, CDI and other formats to ISO, as well as
>   extracting content from them.** You can use it to create ISO images from
>   files and folders on your computer, as well as to encrypt and decrypt
>   existing images, it has also the ability to split big image files, or to merge two or more smaller ones, this software is under the **GPL License.**

I didn't test it myself.