# How to clone a specific partition of a qemu raw disk file to a physical partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, macosx

I have a raw disk file as bellow

```
$fdisk -l Monterey.img

Disk Monterey.img: 14 GiB, 15032385536 bytes, 29360128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B0853EBC-902A-41B6-8BEB-C533A09C0376

Device         Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
Monterey.img1     40   409639   409600  200M EFI System
Monterey.img2 409640 29097943 28688304 13,7G Apple HFS/HFS+
```

It has 2 partitions, 1st for EFI (200MB),  2nd for MacOS installer data

And I have a SSD disk (GUIID type formatted)

```
~$ lsblk
sda           8:0    0 447,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   190M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0 152,6G  0 part /mnt/sda2
├─sda3        8:3    0    96M  0 part 
├─sda4        8:4    0   9,6G  0 part 
├─sda5        8:5    0  15,5G  0 part 
├─sda6        8:6    0  15,5G  0 part 
├─sda7        8:7    0 156,3G  0 part 
└─sda8        8:8    0    97G  0 part /media/minh/M2
```

I want to clone the 2nd partitions from Monterey.img to sda6 (physical partition of internal SSD),

I have tried with

```
$sudo dd if=Monterey.img of=/dev/sda6

29360128+0 records in
29360128+0 records out
15032385536 bytes (15 GB, 14 GiB) copied, 253,909 s, 59,2 MB/s
```

but the result report that unknown type , while other HFS+ partitions are visible and accessible.

Result disk:

[image: Result disk]

If the source disk file type is DMG, it can be cloned by DMG2IMG command as below:

```
$sudo dmg2img -p 2 BaseSystem.dmg /dev/sda6
```

How can I do that for a raw img type ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract iso images to the hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412280/how-to-extract-iso-images-to-the-hard-disk)

Comment: Specifically https://askubuntu.com/a/672704/1004020

Comment: @DanielT: it is different format type and situation , in my case is complete clone partition from raw image to a physical (keep bootloader if any)

Comment: You need to `7z x` first then `dd` . The `dd` will keep the bootloader, but that's only for old (BIOS) systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`losetup` + `dd` can do it.

#### 1. find first unused loop device

```
losetup -f
```

result for example:

```
/dev/loop0
```

#### 2. attach `Monterey.img` to `loop0`

```
losetup /dev/loop0 Monterey.img
partprobe /dev/loop0
lsblk
```

#### 3. clone

```
dd if=/dev/loop0p2 of=/dev/sda6
```

Comment: Thanks very much, It can clone to the physical partition, it can show the partition label and type , but the content is unreadable, error when mounting: "Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/minh/Install macOS Monterey: wrong fs type, bad option, bad super block on /dev/sda6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (udisks-error-quark, 0) ". Does it need to matter size of destination partition must exact same as in RAW img file (current destination is large than image).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os

Comment: My machine install hfsprogs already, others HFS+ is readable , only the new one is unable to read. After using dd command to write sda, it shows label and type okay, but unable to boot OSX.

Comment: Try mount /dev/loop0p2. If works, /dev/sda6 should works too

Comment: the loop is work fine, but the sda6 is not, Do I need to update partition table info or something like that, because the size of sda6 is currently larger than the loop

Comment: try mount /dev/sda6 -o sizelimit=14688411648 /mnt

Comment: I changed the destination partition sda3: sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o sizelimit=14688411648 /mnt/sda3
It mount okay, but error during boot macOS from that partition

Comment: maybe the size of destination partition should be same as origin. Or the Partition type GUID should be same. Which is in Partition Table.